# if else пара условий в скобочках

Tags: python, консоль, if, условия, ос

Как-то не логично работает данная команда:

```
def clear():
  os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

Если читать логически, то звучит так:

> Делаем значение `'cls'`, если `os.name == 'nt'`, в противном случае делаем `clear`

Просто у меня операционная система `Linux` и значение по сути `'nt'` и для очистки экрана используется команда `clear`.

Может неправильно понимаю? Объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator

Comment: Под Linux значение будет равно `'posix'`. NT - это Windows (хотя не все версии Windows относятся к этой линейке).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае используется [тернарный оператор](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator):

```
print('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
#cls
```

пояснение:

```
In [4]: import dis

In [5]: dis.dis("'cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear'")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (os)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (name)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('nt')
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              8 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       14         # если результат сравнения (os.name == 'nt') вернул ложь переходим на 14
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 ('cls')
             12 RETURN_VALUE                       # вернуть 'cls'
        >>   14 LOAD_CONST               2 ('clear')
             16 RETURN_VALUE                       # вернуть 'clear'
```